# Is there a way to identify a target's ancestry?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races

D&D 3.5 has many ways of being a creature that's not a full-blooded member of any one race. From Half-X templates, to X-blooded feats, to Planetouched races and many more. Many of these creatures are similar enough to a pureblooded race to disguise themselves as such, or have the inborn ability to shapeshift in order to hide their nature.

With that in mind: Is there any way to determine a creature's ancestry? I am aware of a Pathfinder spell called "Analyze Ancestry". This is roughly the effect I am looking for, though for my purposes it is enough to simply say "This creature is part X, part Y, and part B" for example. 
I know Pathfinder is considered to be mostly compatible with 3.5, but for the purpose of this question I am looking for official 3.5 material only. The source doesn't matter, as long as it is official, WoTC approved for 3.5 (Including 3.0 material that has not been updated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is no direct equivalent to the third-party *Pathfinder* spell [*analyze ancestry*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/3rd-party-spells/4-winds-fantasy-gaming-3rd-party-spells/analyze-ancestry/), there is in *D&D 3.5e* the official 1st-level sorcerer/wizard spell *discern bloodline* [div] (*Races of Destiny* 165), the description of that spell saying

> The caster can instantly tell the race of the targeted individual, plus any inherited templates possessed by the target (such as celestial or half-dragon). Each round that the caster remains concentrating he can determine the race and inherited templates of another target.

It's possible that the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*legend lore*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#legend-lore) [div] (*Player's Handbook* 246–7) and other high-powered divination spells could yield results similar to the spell *analyze ancestry*, but the best results would likely come from researching an original spell that duplicates the effect of the spell *analyze ancestry* as per Researching Original Spells (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 198). This research takes 3 weeks in an extensive library, costs 3,000 gp, and requires a Spellcraft skill check (DC 13), with success meaning that *either* the caster now knows that spell *or* the DM has determined the spell's not a viable spell for this campaign. (Note that in the latter case, this is also the DM telling the PCs that *The adventure is finding this information, so get that information the old-fashioned way!*)